# What is the meaning of"Simplicity is the last step of art"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

"Simplicity is the last step of art. "

—Bruce lee

Is it express **A special skill or ability is very easy to exhibit at the end stage...***

Comment: Googling around, I think the the complete quote is "Simplicity is the last step of art and the beginning of nature", as testified [here](https://www.tygertyger.com.au/boxing-simplicity-is-the-last-step-in-art-and-the-beginning-of-nature/) and elsewhere.  As to what Bruce Lee meant by that, I would think we need to go to a biography of him, or to find meaning within the world of martial arts or in [spirituality derived from martial arts](https://slife.org/bruce-lee-quotes/), although no doubt other artists may find their own meanings in their respective fields.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple is it the intended meaning that I mentioned?

Comment: there is a typo there (do you mean, "at the end stage.."?), and it would be helpful to complete the sentence.  But if that's all you have, maybe that's **partly** what Bruce Lee meant, but if we look at other Bruce Lee quotes from the "On Simplicity" section of [this page](https://slife.org/bruce-lee-quotes/), I think it means (in martial arts) that a very effective move (punch, kick, etc.) should be simple (direct hit, concentrated) and natural (like how a tiger attacks its prey).  It's "last step" because by then you're an expert martial arts practitioner.

Comment: Your bold section really doesn't say anything at all as it stands - the end stage of what?

Comment: In the same vein, Leonardo da Vinci said that "Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication" and Plato wrote “Beauty of style and harmony and grace and good rhythm depend on simplicity.”

Comment: @DoneWithThis. I mean "when one is at the end end stage of practice"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling around, I think the the complete quote is "Simplicity is the last step of art and the beginning of nature", as testified [here](https://www.tygertyger.com.au/boxing-simplicity-is-the-last-step-in-art-and-the-beginning-of-nature/) and elsewhere.  But even so, aphorisms like this are notorious for having MULTIPLE meanings beyond the dictionary meanings, thus beyond the scope of ELL SE.  However, I try to answer your question below.

What did Bruce Lee meant by his quote on simplicity?  I found a group of other quotes listed in the "On Simplicity" section of [this extensive list](https://slife.org/bruce-lee-quotes/) of Bruce Lee quotes.  When combined with

> Simplicity is the shortest distance between two points.

and

> It’s not the daily increase but daily decrease. Hack away at the unessential.

your proposed meaning as simplicity obtained "when one is at the end end stage of practice" is plausible in that an expert martial artist can kick/punch with direct hit like a tiger jumps on its prey, thus delivering a simple single-move forceful act that decapacitate his/her opponent.  This ability can only be obtained by "hacking away at the unessential" movements through practice.

As a classical pipe organist, this kind of simplicity is ALSO hammered into me by my organ professor at the university where although I was a proficient pianist when I started (> 10 years), I have to **re-learn** how to even touch a single key with my finger with utmost attention to the muscle I use to press and (more importantly!!) to depress/release the key.  I had to spend **a whole semester** practicing elementary "moves" through exercises he developed for his students so it becomes ingrained in me as a habit.  After a few years of training, I was then able to play a [Bach Trio Sonata piece](https://imslp.org/wiki/Organ_Sonata_No.1_in_E-flat_major,_BWV_525_(Bach,_Johann_Sebastian)) where there can be a dozen key presses with both hands and feet per second because of extreme economy and simplicity of movements (see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PpNKoYILsE) for an example.)